# for loop at the bash commandline

Tags: bash

I am having trouble with **for loops** at the command line.  Basically they appear to prompt for with a new line without exec.

- `$(for i in {1..5}; do echo $i; done)` simply hangs, never execs
- `echo $(for i in {1..5}; do echo $i; done)` produces a command substitution error.

Running `bash --norc` works.  However lint `shellcheck` of .bashrc shows no problems.

Debugging with `strace bash ~/.bashrc` didnt produce anything noteworthy.

What should I check for next, to get a clean terminal working?

Thanks

bash version 4.3.11

Comment: What happens if you use a `for` loop without the `$(...)`?

Comment: Both of these are valid syntax, as your fresh shell confirms. What do you mean by "prompt for with a new line"? Is it the (by default) `>` prompt you get if you just type `while` and hit enter? Have you checked your aliases with `alias`?

Comment: In a "stock" shell, the first command should produce `1: command not found` and the second should just output the numbers 1 through 5 on one line.

Comment: If you know it's your dotfiles messing something up, then using `PS4=':${BASH_SOURCE}:$LINENO+' bash -x -l -i` to log the commands they run (and which file and line every such command comes from) is a pretty good place to start.

Comment: That said, insofar as this is a question about diagnosing configuration of an interactive shell as opposed to a question about writing scripts, it's probably a better fit for [unix.se] than StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I get when I enter those snippets on the command line:

```
prompt> $(for i in {1..5}; do echo $i; done)
1: command not found

prompt> echo $(for i in {1..5}; do echo $i; done)
1 2 3 4 5
```

In the first case, the syntax itself is valid, but since you don't have any command or variable assignment, `bash` is just doing the command substitution, and then attempting to parse the output of the command substitution as a command. It's exactly as if you'd done this:

```
prompt> 1 2 3 4 5
1: command not found
```

Since you're just getting a hang on this command, and no output, then there must be something else going on that's most likely not related to bash itself.

In the second case, for me anyway, it works. The numbers get echoed out on a single line because you didn't quote the command substitution, so the newlines are just treated as delimiters, and it's essentially identical to:

```
echo 1 2 3 4 5
```

If you quote the command substitution, you get this:

```
prompt> echo "$(for i in {1..5}; do echo $i; done)"
1
2
3
4
5
```

Bottom line: Your loop syntax is valid, as is using it inside a command substitution. Just don't expect the loop's output to be interpreted as a valid bash command. That is, unless you actually have a an executable named `1` in your `PATH`.

Comment: Hi, it was an error in the .bashrc.  Isolated the problem by going through the file line-by-line.  Even shellcheck did not detect this.